# Linear algebra proof that there is an inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

so I have $A - B + A^2 - AB = I$. I'm afraid I'm stuck now, how can I prove that $A-B$ has an inverse?

Comment: Factorize the given equation.

Answer (score 3):

You can factor your expression like this:

$$ (A-B)+A(A-B) = I\implies (I+A)(A-B)= I$$

So $I+A$ is inverse for $A-B$.

Comment: thank you, this helps :)